# How to make a button check an id

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have been trying to make a login page for my website but I am trying to make it so when you click "Login". It checks the value and makes sure it is exactly "admin" for the ID, and "password" for the password. I attempted to look up some answers but the answers I've come across I don't get much. If you could help, that'd be great!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Dashboard">
<meta name="keyword" content="Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, 
Responsive, Fluid, Retina">

<title>Halifax</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--external css-->
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media 
queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"> 
</script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"> 
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <!--*********************MAIN CONTENT************* -->

  <div id="login-page">
    <div class="container">

          <form class="form-login" action="index.html">
            <h2 class="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" 
placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
                <br>
                <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Password">
                <label class="checkbox">
                <script>
                var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
                var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                </script>
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="login.html#myModal"> 
Forgot Password?</a>

                    </span>
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" href="index.html" 
type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>
                <hr>

                <div class="login-social-link centered">
                <p>or you can sign in via your social network</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-facebook" type="submit"><i 
class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-twitter" type="submit"><i 
class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</button>
                </div>
                <div class="registration">
                    Don't have an account yet?<br/>
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        Create an account
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" 
role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data- 
dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Forgot Password ?</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <p>Enter your e-mail address below to reset 
your password.</p>
                              <input type="text" name="email" 
 placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no- 
 fix">

                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn- 
default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                              <button class="btn btn-theme" 
type="button">Submit</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- modal -->

          </form>       

    </div>
  </div>

<!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--BACKSTRETCH-->
<!-- You can use an image of whatever size. This script will stretch to fit 
in any screen size.-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
    $.backstretch("assets/img/login-bg.jpg", {speed: 500});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if some of it is not in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

- Your form points to `index.html`, meaning you have no **[server-side validation](http://net-informations.com/faq/asp/validation.htm)**. You should be validating your logins server-side with something like PHP, ASP.NET or Python, else you open yourself to a **raft** of security vulnerabilities.
- Your `<button>` has an `href` attribute, **[which is invalid](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp)**. `href` can only be applied to `<a>`, `<area>`, `<base>` and `<link>`. You only want it on your `<a>` element.
- You have a `<script>` inside your `<form>`. While not invalid, you'll certainly want to separate out this logic for clarity, and make use of **[Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)** by adding an event listener to the form.

Having said all that, you set up IDs for your two elements (`#id` and `#pass`), and correctly reference them in your JavaScript:

```
var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
```

However, you're not actually **doing** anything with these two variables. You'll want some conditional logic that checks the value of these two inputs, and does something if they match the given values. Note that you'll want to **set** these values when the button is **clicked**; otherwise they'll be blank.

This can be seen in the following, which attaches an event listener to the button click, prevents default submission with `e.preventDefault()`, checks the values in the two input fields, and if they're both `admin`, submits the form.

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent submission
  var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (id == 'admin' && pass == 'admin') { // Check inputs
    form.submit(); // Submit the form
  }
})
```

```html
<form class="form-login" action="index.html">
  <div class="login-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, note that this client-side login validation should be **supplementary** to server-side logic. Client-side validation of logins is almost as weak as locking your door with a Twistee rather than a key. Always validate logins server-side!

Comment: Thank you for helping me! That got the login page finished but I have  quick question. Because my dashboard is set to index.html. People would go there on the start? How do I put a lock on it of some sort?

Comment: No probs! And you probably wouldn't want your dashboard to be `index.html`. You'd want it to be something like `dashboard.html`, and have a 'welcome' page for `.index.html`. Then you would point the `<form>` element's `action` to the `dashboard.html`. Again though, having said this, nothing would stop someone visiting `dashboard.html` manually and completely bypassing your login. I would **strongly** advise you use a server-side language (and database) to prevent this -- that way you can make use of sessions and require the session to be set in order for the dashboard to be viewed.